# how do i handle POST response

Tags: angular

Hey im trying to get some data from my server using angular POST i'm getting the parameter i send and i get a response from the server. I'm just not able to handle my response and actually get the parameters i want.

if i look in my console i get this response:

```
data from server Response {_body: " {"data":[{"temperature":"20","dispenses":5,"lates…08:36:15","latest_reset":"2017-10-15 08:42:47"}]}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
```

how would i go about grapping the temperature? or should i maybe change my return JSON? please guide me in the right direction

my angular code :

```
getCustomerData()
    {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        urlSearchParams.append('customerID', this.customerID);
        //urlSearchParams.append('password', 'wtf');
        let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

       this.http.post('HIDDEN BUT WORKS',body,{headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
        // Read the result field from the JSON response.
        console.log('data from server', data);
        let jsonResponse = data.json();
        //console.log('nextstep',data.temperature);
        console.log('hmm',jsonResponse._body.data.temperature);
        //console.log('size',data.toString);
    },(error) => {
        console.log('error', error);

      });
    }
```

my response code:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {        
            $json[] = array(
            'temperature' => $temperature,
            'dispenses' => $dispenses,  
            'latest_cleaning' => $latest_cleaning,      
            'latest_reset' => $latest_reset     
            );          
        }


        $finalresult['data'] = $json;

        //logToFile('data.log',json_encode($finalresult));
        echo json_encode($finalresult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your code, you should do:

```
this.http.post('HIDDEN BUT WORKS',body,{headers: headers})
.map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log('temperature', data[0].temperature);
})
```

you can also use `data[0]` to access the others properties.

Comment: after removing my $finalresult['data'] = $json; both your answers work! TY

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
this.http.post('HIDDEN BUT WORKS',body,{headers: headers}).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data', data);
})
```

Comment: This will return : data {data: Array(1)} How will access the temperature parameter ? ect

Comment: console.log('temerature', data[0].temperature);

Comment: after removing my $finalresult['data'] = $json; both your answers work! TY